# Android Studio : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-import

My friend Gave me a project which was built in Windows platform and I have ubuntu. So when I import the project I am getting this error,

```
Error:(1, 0) Cause: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

How can get my project running. I have tried all the possible solutions but didn't work any one of them.

I have already point my SDK path and using JDK 1.7.0. Using Gradle 2.14.1 which is latest one.

Here is my gradle.build file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.lenovo.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-' +
                'api-client-gson:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
        compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.3'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Any solution would be appreciated. I am stuck since last 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have already point my SDK path and using JDK 1.7.0

You need JDK 1.8 with the new version of Studio and the build tools.

Comment: I changed my JDK path to 8 - Oracle and now I am getting this error, "Install Repository and sync project". any idea?

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5

Comment: Thnx, For above error I have to install ConstraintLayout from SDK manager > SDK Tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use JDK 1.7. The project was built on 1.8 ( 52.0 - refer this link [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)). So, probaby using 1.8 JDK and JRE may work for you.